# Let $0 \ne u \in \mathbb{C}^n$ fixed and consider for every $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ the matrix $E(v)=uv^*$. Find all eigenvalues of $E(v)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $0 \ne u \in \mathbb{C}^n$ fixed and consider for every $v \in
>  \mathbb{C}^n$ the matrix $E(v)=uv^*$.
>
> Find all eigenvalues of $E(v)$.

$E(v)=uv^*=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
u_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
{v_1}^* & \cdots  &{v_n} ^* 
\end{pmatrix}
=\left(v_1^*\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
u_n
\end{pmatrix}| ... |
v_n^*\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
u_n
\end{pmatrix} \right)
$

Is this correct? I would conclude from this that $E(v)$ has rank 1. How could I find the eigenvalues ? Does this mean that there are $n-1$ eigenvectors with eigenvalue 0 ? What could be the last eigenvalue ? I'm stuck here, a hint would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $uv^\ast$ has rank $1$, so it has $n-1$ zero eigenvalues. Now you can see what the remaining eigenvalue is by considering $uv^\ast u$.

Comment: $uv^*u=(v^*u)u$ as $v^*u \in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore the eigenvalues are $v^*u$ and $0$. Is this correct ?

Comment: @Kasper Yes, that's correct.